# ModuleNotFoundError in werkzug after unistall and install

Tags: flask, werkzeug

I have a service that uses the Flask and werkzeug libraries.
I recently transferred the code from a Linux server to a Python server.

**My program crashes every day and I fix it by uninstalling werkzeug and reinstalling werkzeug.**

**A day later, I encounter the werkzeug.utils error in the logs again.**

The error message is:

```
App 2048818 output: /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
App 2048818 output:   import sys, os, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
App 2048818 output: Traceback (most recent call last):
App 2048818 output:   File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: app_module = load_app()
App 2048818 output:   File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
App 2048818 output:   File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: module = _load(spec)
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
App 2048818 output:   File "/home/inbotioc/public_html/sitemap-checker/passenger_wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'sitemap-checker-pycode.py')
App 2048818 output:   File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: module = _load(spec)
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
App 2048818 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
App 2048818 output:   File "sitemap-checker-pycode.py", line 5, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: from flask import Flask, request
App 2048818 output:   File "/home/inbotioc/virtualenv/public_html/sitemap-checker/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: from . import json as json
App 2048818 output:   File "/home/inbotioc/virtualenv/public_html/sitemap-checker/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: from ..globals import current_app
App 2048818 output:   File "/home/inbotioc/virtualenv/public_html/sitemap-checker/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 6, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: from werkzeug.local import LocalProxy
App 2048818 output:   File "/home/inbotioc/virtualenv/public_html/sitemap-checker/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: from .test import Client as Client
App 2048818 output:   File "/home/inbotioc/virtualenv/public_html/sitemap-checker/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 41, in <module>
App 2048818 output:     
App 2048818 output: from .utils import cached_property
App 2048818 output: ModuleNotFoundError: 
App 2048818 output: No module named 'werkzeug.utils'
```

packages:

```
blinker==1.6.2
cachelib==0.10.2
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
click==8.1.7
elementpath==4.1.5
exceptiongroup==1.1.3
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-Session==0.5.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
lxml==4.9.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
packaging==23.2
pluggy==1.3.0
pytest==7.4.2
requests==2.31.0
tomli==2.0.1
urllib3==2.0.5
Werkzeug==3.0.1
xmlschema==2.5.0
zipp==3.17.0
```

My program crashes every day and I fix it by uninstalling werkzeug and reinstalling werkzeug.

Please help me :((

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `pip install -U werkzeug`

- Also, Did you check if you are in right environment?

Comment: Yes, I have done this too, but the service is temporarily run and the mentioned error message occurs again after a few hours.